# How to string replace a symbol from array and split?

Tags: javascript, php

I have

```
$dataSavedBlocks = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'jsonBlock');
var_dump($dataSavedBlocks);
```

Which gives:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(534) "{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":999,"terapia_intensiva":251,"totale_ospedalizzati":1250,"isolamento_domiciliare":1526,"totale_attualmente_positivi":2776,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":257,"dimessi_guariti":54,"deceduti":142,"totale_casi":2972,"tamponi":17868} | ,{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":82,"terapia_intensiva":19,"totale_ospedalizzati":101,"isolamento_domiciliare":311,"totale_attualmente_positivi":412,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":17,"dimessi_guariti":12,"deceduti":18,"totale_casi":442,"tamponi":3019} | " }
```

I tried:

```
$dataSavedBlocks = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'jsonBlock');
$dataCustom = implode("| ,", $dataSavedBlocks[0]); 
$dataCustom = str_replace("| ,",",",$dataCustom);
$dataCustom = explode(",", $dataCustom);

var_dump($dataCustom);
```

I get:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ...
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

I need a correct json to parse it in js:

```
var customJsonData = JSON.parse('<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>');
```

But I have `| ,` as a separator and I cannot exclude it for other reasons when I save it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you imploding if you already have a string?

Comment: You could try `json_encode($dataSavedBlocks)` which will give you a list of json strings - json encoded.

Comment: @El_Vanja I was trying many ways, I don't know how to split with | ,

Comment: @NigelRen yeah but how do I replace |, with , and split ?

Comment: What exactly is your desired end result? An array with individual object json strings?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes exactly, this is getting closer but I have backslahes     `$dataCustom = json_encode($dataSavedBlocks);
    $dataCustom = str_replace(" | ,",",",$dataCustom);
    $dataCustom = explode(",", $dataCustom);`

Comment: @mplungjan tried `var customJsonData = JSON.parse('<?php echo $dataSavedBlocks; ?>');`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to replace `|` with an empty string and to wrap the result in square brackets:

```
$jsonBlock = '{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":999,"terapia_intensiva":251,"totale_ospedalizzati":1250,"isolamento_domiciliare":1526,"totale_attualmente_positivi":2776,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":257,"dimessi_guariti":54,"deceduti":142,"totale_casi":2972,"tamponi":17868} | ,{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":82,"terapia_intensiva":19,"totale_ospedalizzati":101,"isolamento_domiciliare":311,"totale_attualmente_positivi":412,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":17,"dimessi_guariti":12,"deceduti":18,"totale_casi":442,"tamponi":3019} | ';

$json = '[' . str_replace(' | ', '', $jsonBlock) . ']';

var_dump($json);
```

The result would be:

```
string(530) "[{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":999,"terapia_intensiva":251,"totale_ospedalizzati":1250,"isolamento_domiciliare":1526,"totale_attualmente_positivi":2776,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":257,"dimessi_guariti":54,"deceduti":142,"totale_casi":2972,"tamponi":17868},{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":82,"terapia_intensiva":19,"totale_ospedalizzati":101,"isolamento_domiciliare":311,"totale_attualmente_positivi":412,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":17,"dimessi_guariti":12,"deceduti":18,"totale_casi":442,"tamponi":3019}]"
```

```js
const json = JSON.parse('[{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":999,"terapia_intensiva":251,"totale_ospedalizzati":1250,"isolamento_domiciliare":1526,"totale_attualmente_positivi":2776,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":257,"dimessi_guariti":54,"deceduti":142,"totale_casi":2972,"tamponi":17868},{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":82,"terapia_intensiva":19,"totale_ospedalizzati":101,"isolamento_domiciliare":311,"totale_attualmente_positivi":412,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":17,"dimessi_guariti":12,"deceduti":18,"totale_casi":442,"tamponi":3019}]');

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS can handle the string

```js
const str = `{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":999,"terapia_intensiva":251,"totale_ospedalizzati":1250,"isolamento_domiciliare":1526,"totale_attualmente_positivi":2776,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":257,"dimessi_guariti":54,"deceduti":142,"totale_casi":2972,"tamponi":17868} | ,{"date":"3/25/20","ricoverati_con_sintomi":82,"terapia_intensiva":19,"totale_ospedalizzati":101,"isolamento_domiciliare":311,"totale_attualmente_positivi":412,"nuovi_attualmente_positivi":17,"dimessi_guariti":12,"deceduti":18,"totale_casi":442,"tamponi":3019} | " }`
   .replace(/\|/g,"").replace(/ " }/,"")

console.log(JSON.parse("["+str+"]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do and worked

```
<?php

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $dataSavedBlocks = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'jsonBlock');
    $dataCustom = json_encode($dataSavedBlocks[0]); 
    $dataCustom = str_replace('|', '', $dataCustom);
    $dataCustom = stripslashes($dataCustom);
?>
```

js

```
    var myJson = '<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>';
    var result = myJson.substring(1, myJson.length-1);
    var customJsonData = JSON.parse("["+result+"]");
```